# How to change CSS where id=array(index)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

i just write an small code that should change CSS of X ids.

I have 3 ids in HTML objects (every element has 1 Class)=

> element 1 id = "p1" class="test1"
>   element 2 id = "p2" class="test1"
>   element 3 id = "p3" class="test1"

i create two Arrays :

```
 var statArray = ["p1","p3"];
 var array = ["p1","p3"];
```

than i check if Array 1 = Array 2

```
for (var ix = 0; ix < array.length; ix++) {
if (array[ix] === statArray[ix])
```

Now i will change the css (background-color) of the ids.

How can i change the ids where id = array[ix]?

my attempt:

```
$(".test1").attr(array[ix]).css("background-color","#ff0000");
```

Comment: `$('#' + array.join(', #')).css("background-color","#ff0000");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this

```
for (var ix = 0; ix < array.length; ix++) {
    if (array[ix] === statArray[ix]){
        $(".test1#"+array[ix]).css("background-color","#F00");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use id selector `#` or name-value selector:

```
$("#"+array[ix]).css("background-color","#ff0000");
```

or

```
$("[id="+array[ix]+"]").css("background-color","#ff0000");
```

Comment: performance-of-jquery-selectors-with-id http://stackoverflow.com/a/13508551/1719752

Answer (score 1):

I would better not requery DOM in loop at all. You can cache result in variable:

```
var $test = $(".test1");

for (var ix = 0; ix < array.length; ix++) {
    if (array[ix] === statArray[ix]) {
        $test.filter('#' + array[ix]).css("background-color", "#ff0000");
    }
}
```