# Does the number of IDs in a page impact the efficiency of the selectors?

Tags: jquery, html, performance

In a big html page, does the speed of selecting an element by `id` depend on the total number of elements that have a defined `id`?

Consider the following scenario: We have a big html page with tens of thousands of dom elements, and we have 10000+ elements that look like this:

```
<div id="tooltip555">
     <label>Tooltip</label>
     <div>
          <i class="icon"></i>
          <span>Tooltip body</span>
          ...
     </div>
</div>
```

I know it is faster to select an element directly by ID ( [Performance of jQuery selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508472/performance-of-jquery-selectors-with-id) ), so technically, instead of selecting the components inside `tooltip555` with a chained selector (like '#tooltip555 > div > span') would it be faster if I generate an id for each of its children that I plan to use and select it using `#tooltip555_div_span`, but resulting in 3 times more dom elements with defined ids?

Comment: Number of `id` attributes, no. Number of elements, yes. However unless you have tens of thousands of elements it shouldn't be an issue. In this case I would use the `#tooltip555 > div > span` selector. The matches set of elements being filtered will be drastically reduced by the id selector so performance should be fine.

Comment: Well the first thought that comes to my mind is that once you specify a selector, jQuery **has** to go through all the selectors once atleast, so the `id`, `class` etc. shouldn't matter.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I'm asking this because I do have performance issues, I have a one-page website that updates its content dynamically and more elements are generated then removed, resulting in some scripts involving many selections being laggy. I know I should re-design some algorithms but I am just wondering if I can save some time using more/less IDs and reducing/increasing complexity of selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be much faster if you avoid using the selector as it requires parsing the DOM as opposed to id's which are pre-stored in a map by most browsers. For example you can access your elements with id through window["elementId"] in chrome. Also don't forget unless you are using ":first" jquery will keep looking in the dom even after finding the first (and only) element.

I would use: $(document.getElementById("elementId")) for the best performance.

But then again I highly doubt your performance issues derive from this, 99% of the time it is excessive dom manipulation or memory leak causing the problems.